# How do I loop the function callback with a random delay in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So my Phaser 3 game requires to call a function spawn with random delay each time between 3s to 6s.
Here is what I tried :

```
Enemies﻿ = this.time.addEvent({ 
delay:  Phaser.Math.Between(3000,6000),  
loop: true, 
callback: spawn, 
callbackScope: this });﻿﻿
```

But this code does not works. The delay is chosen at random only once and then that value is used throughout.

Comment: yes, that how it works. As delay parameter is a fixed value. Try to make delay a function thus need to evaluated every time?

Comment: It's not working. It is doing the same thing. The function gets evaluated once and that value is used throughout.

Comment: does time has other function except `addEvent` such as `scheduleEvent` or something like this?

Comment: I did not saw any property like that but you should check out this link for more on time.[Timer](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/timer/)

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [your own link](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/timer/) that there is a `oneShot timer`. You can use that inside the spawn function.

Now a new one-shot timer with a random delay will be created when `spawn()` is called. The timer then calls `spawn()` again...

```
function spawn() {
     let delay = Phaser.Math.Between(3000,6000)
     var timer = scene.time.delayedCall(delay, spawn, args, scope); 
}

spawn()
```